# What are possible resolutions of the length unit paradox stemming from Zeno's Paradoxes?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, paradox, zeno-of-elea

The paradox in question: If every unit of length is made up of smaller units of length, it seems that you need to have units of length before a unit of length can come into existence. But this is clearly contradictory.

This paradox would seem to imply the following. Say you have two lines lying exactly on top of one another "|", and you want to slide one off the other to create space between the two, so that it now looks like this "||". If we need units of length before a unit of length can exist, then it seems we cannot create a length of distance between these two lines when we started with none, as we would need to have some length of distance already between them before we could have any length of distance between them.

Where does this reasoning go wrong?

Comment: I do not see why smaller units of length need to "precede in existence" (whatever that means) bigger ones, why can't they all exist eternally, or "come into existence" simultaneously, or bigger ones first? Also, you "existence" is ambiguous between length unit (as a physical aspect) and the notion of length unit. Why can't sliding of the lines happen physically even if there were no notions of length units, or of length and lines for that matter? Or if those came to be distinguished only later after the whole process happened multiple times, which is how it historically was?

Comment: I have the same question as Conifold: "Why can't sliding of the lines happen physically even if there were no notions of length units, or of length and lines for that matter?"

Comment: The statement "every unit of length is made up of smaller units of length" seems to contradict the way we work with units. To work with units, one fixes one value (one meter, one kilogram are canonical examples), and then one subdivides as desired. Why would a contradiction arise from that?

Comment: @Conifold, the same argument can be applied to the concept of distance. If every distance is made up of shorter distances, we need to have distance before we can have distance. While they could come into existence at the same time, the fact that you first need the shorter distances before you can have / comprehend the full distance implies, to me at least, that one must come before the other.

Comment: This is not Zeno's argument at all, his argument is that we need to *cover* half the distance before we cover the whole distance. As for what we need to *comprehend*, I do not see why we can not comprehend all possible distances at once, they are all of a kind, and even if not why are shorter ones "easier" to comprehend and come first? This seems to conflate order of size with the order of understanding.

Comment: @Conifold it is an equivalent problem to that raised by Zeno's dichotomy. The runner cannot move because there is no first point. The reason there is no first point is the paradox I mentioned above in my post. To see why shorter distances must precede longer distances, consider the following scenario: Two rods lie perfectly on top of one another at one moment. One rod then slides to the right, creating a distance between them. No matter what distance you have between them there must have been a shorter distance that existed before it in this scenario.

Comment: I feel you have found yet another paradox associated with our usual ideas of time and space. There are many of them, and they all appear in the foundations of mathematics and in metaphysics. They go away if we do not relfy these phenomena but follow Kant.

Comment: Consider another scenario: two rods are at some distance and we start moving them together, then the half comes after the whole. Consider a third scenario, where the above two happen next to each other. This shows a bigger problem with your reasoning, comprehension is not tied to any particular "scenarios", if there is indeed a paradox in *comprehension* of distance (as opposed to motion, which is a particular occurence) you need an argument that does not rely on scenarios. As it is the reply is trivial, there is no paradox.

Comment: @Conifold "Comprehension" was a spontaneously chosen word I felt would be a decent way of describing the paradox with units of length. It is not my primary position. The paradox I am trying to point to is a logical one, best captured by the following: before something can be said to have moved any amount of distance, it must have already moved shorter distances. This applies equally to every example you proposed, I believe.

Comment: Concepts are not individual things, they do not have to be grasped one at a time, let alone in the order of empirical appearance. I can grasp the concept of distance between two things as a separating interval with no specific length, this is what we usually do, length is incidental to the concept. Then I can grasp the part-whole relation of two intervals, so I have all I need before any motion even begins. In fact, Zeno's reasoning relies on this, his paradoxes exploit tension between sensible change and "timeless" concepts we attempt to capture it with.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Zeno-like paradoxes involve an infinite sequence of events buried in the language used in the problem.  Your example appears to go down the path of doubling the distance between the lines enough times to achieve the desired separation, while Zeno's original paradox depends on halving the distance.

In both cases, the tricky part is coming up with a language to describe the problem which is capable of describing this infinite series of steps without contradiction.  The problematic portion is typically identifiable with an appeal to reason, such as your "... it *seems* we cannot create..."  It is dependent on the listener agreeing with such a statement.  If they agree with that statement, then typically they agree that the problem is paradoxical, and thus there must be something wrong.

If one's listener does not automatically agree with you about this statement, one must defend it.  Defending it is where the really precise language often comes into play.  Mathematics, for instance, has a extraordinarily precise ways of dealing with the concept of infinity, and prides itself on its self-consistency.  If one phrases the problem in the language of mathematics, then one can use the strength of mathematics to argue for their position.

However, the current "preferred" solution to Zeno's paradox is calculus.  Calculus handles these infinities in a way that *appears* to be consistent with the world we live in without causing paradoxes from self-consistency issues.  If your efforts to phrase the question in mathematical terms leads you to use notations from calculus, one will find that the issue is dealt with by the handling of limits which elide away issues that might come up regarding infinitesimals.  These methods have been heavily analyzed over the years, so lead people to have a great deal of confidence in answers derived from them.

In my opinion, your Zeno-like argument is going down a direction which would be proven using set theory.  There are systems for handling sets like ZFC which one would be tempted to use, but your particular construction is likely to go down the path of having an infinite descending set, which is forbidden in ZFC by the axiom of regularity.  One would need to look at different solutions, such as [Quine atoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement#Quine_atoms) which are used in some non-well-founded set theories.  Such set theories are much less popular than their well-founded brethren, so they do not encourage the same level of confidence.

Comment: Currently, this is nothing more than a statement of your opinion without argumentation or references. Please edit this to make it objective (not with the aim to convince someone) and add proper references. keelan◆ [hehe kidding!]